# code 422 status failure message Invalid Payload

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, get, frameworks, restsharp

I want to get tracking detail using rest api My code returns the following message:
{"code":422,"status":"failure","message":"Invalid Payload! Please check the api documentation or contact at dev@smartlane.pk.","errors":{"store_order_id":["The store order id field is required."]}}
How to resolve this I am using VB.net

```
Dim client = New RestClient("https://v2.Smartlane.dev/api/consignment/track")
        client.Timeout = -1
        Dim request = New RestRequest(Method.GET)
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer -------------------------------")
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
        Dim body = "{" + """store_order_id"":[" + """AS41929""" + "]" + "}"
        request.AddParameter("application/json", body, ParameterType.RequestBody)
        Dim response As IRestResponse = client.Execute(request)
        Console.WriteLine(response.Content)
```

Comment: What happened when you contacted the email address given in the error message?

Comment: Sorry, not to point out the obvious.  Doesn't the message tell you everything you need to know? _The store order id field is required_.  Are you 100% `Dim body = "{" + """store_order_id"":[" + """AS41929""" + "]" + "}"` is the correct way to present this with the square brackets?  There are better mechanisms around to build json strings that may help

Comment: However I also used this 
        Dim NewData As New JSON_LStatus
        NewData.store_order_id = OrderIDs.ToArray
        Dim body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(NewData)
        request.AddParameter("application/json", body, ParameterType.RequestBody)
to convert to json but same error of 422 occurs

Comment: In the property name `"store_order_id"`, `id` is singular not plural (i.e. not `ids`) so are you sure it should be an array, and not a single value?  I.e. is there a chance it should it be `"store_order_id" : "AS41929"`?